# Boot U-boot from RAM using U-boot

Tags: embedded-linux, bootloader, u-boot, tftp

I would like to boot an U-boot image from RAM using another U-boot. I loaded the U-boot image in the RAM using tftp `tftp 0x90000000 u-boot.img` and tried to run it with `go 0x90000000` but nothing happens. I guess there are some conflicts concerning the initializations. When I went to the U-boot code, I found in the file **/arch/arm/cpu/armv7/start.S** the following comment **do important init only if we don't start from memory!**. So I have some questions.

- First of all, is it possible to do that?
- Any Idea of what are those *important init*?
- And is there anything else I need to remove from the u-boot code?

Comment: Typically you cannot load and execute U-Boot at an arbitrary address.  U-Boot is typically built (i.e. linked) to load and start at a specific address defined by **CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE**.

Comment: @sawdust Thank you. I didn't knew that. I succeeded to boot the u-boot but I can't boot a linux kernel with it. it is stuck in the **Verifying Checksum ...** of  **bootm** function. Any ideas ?

Comment: Sounds like the stack and/or text has been overwritten.  You need to locate where everything is in memory, and draw a memory map.  Note that U-Boot can relocate itself from its loaded address to high memory.  Consider enabling debug output as mentioned at the beginning of **arch/arm/lib/board.c**.  The salient messages would be *"New Stack Pointer is:..."* and  *""Now running in RAM - U-Boot at:..."*

Answer (score 1):

I spent a couple of days trying to do the same thing in order to avoid the hassle of burning each new image version to flash, after all, if I have a working bootloader why not load a new version from it. I think [this](https://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/CanUBootBeConfiguredSuchThatItCanBeStartedInRAM) section of U-Boot documentation page explains perfectly why this not <del>im</del>possible.

> If you want to start U-Boot from another boot loader, you must disable a lot of code, i. e. all initialization parts that already have been performed by this other boot loader...

---

> The code you have to disable contains the most critical parts in U-Boot, i. e. these are the areas where 99% or more of all errors are located when you port U-Boot to a new hardware. In the result, your RAM image may work, but in the end you will need a full image to program the flash memory with it, and then you will have to enable all this highly critical and completely untested code.